# Xuggler - opening mp4 files crashes/blocks program

Tags: java, video, mp4, xuggler

Short version:

Opening/reading mp4 files with Xuggler sometimes does not work properly but causes program to crash.

Long version:

In my program i read, modify and write video files. It works fine with most formats i tested (avi, flv, mpg, mkv).
The Xuggler functions i use are mostly:

```
//Example 1
IContainer container = IContainer.make();
int result = container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null);
```

and

```
//Example 2
 IMediaReader filmReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(filename);
 filmReader.readPacket();
 filmReader.close();
```

**Working on mp4 file is lottery. Some files work mostly fine. Some files work with the Example 1 but not with Example 2 or vice versa. With some files program runs if it's Debug mode and with some it does not run in debug mode.**

**The effect i usually get is an error (look at the bottom of post).**

**The answer i'm looking for is why this happens and more importantly is it possible to fix?**

Problem is especially hard for me to investigate because it seems semi random. It may behave differently in debug mode, sometimes even the time i wait in debug mode before pressing continue may cause program to run properly or crash.

Adding seemingly unrelated code may cause program to stop working with some files. For example:

Adding line:

```
 IContainer container1 = IContainer.make();
```

Before program:

```
 IMediaReader filmReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(filename);
 filmReader.readPacket();
 filmReader.close();

 IContainer container = IContainer.make();
 int result = container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null);
 System.out.println(result);
```

Cause crashes with files that worked properly before.

The error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ee76520,                 pid=4448, tid=7192
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b26) (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle6554930242940580036.dll+0x736520]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client     versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Michal\Java Workspace\TestMP4\hs_err_pid4448.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

The log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ee76520, pid=1164, tid=8360
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b26) (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle7482689414368935779.dll+0x736520]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000021fe800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=8360, stack(0x0000000002200000,0x0000000002300000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000003e1130, RBX=0x0000000058fc0120, RCX=0x00000000003e1130, RDX=0x0000000000000009
RSP=0x00000000022fdd60, RBP=0x00000000003e0870, RSI=0x00000000003e2130, RDI=0x0000000000000004
R8 =0x000000006ee77580, R9 =0x000000006ee76490, R10=0x000000005902e880, R11=0x00000000003d16a0
R12=0x00000000003d1ea0, R13=0x0000000000000004, R14=0x0000000000000184, R15=0x000000006fab8f20
RIP=0x000000006ee76520, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000022fdd60)
0x00000000022fdd60:   000000006ee76665 000000006ee774c5
0x00000000022fdd70:   000000006ee77505 000000006ee77545
0x00000000022fdd80:   000000006ee77585 000000006ee79426
0x00000000022fdd90:   000000006fab8f20 00000000003e1130
0x00000000022fdda0:   0000000058fc25e0 0000000002650006
0x00000000022fddb0:   3fe0000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000022fddc0:   40c7760000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000022fddd0:   3fe0000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000022fdde0:   0000000058fc35e0 000000006ea45d24
0x00000000022fddf0:   3f40624dd2f1a9fc 0000000000000000
0x00000000022fde00:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000022fde10:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000022fde20:   0000000058fcc4e0 000000006fab7320
0x00000000022fde30:   0000000055dbdc5d 0000000058fc0080
0x00000000022fde40:   0000000000000000 00000000003e0870
0x00000000022fde50:   00000000003e0870 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006ee76520)
0x000000006ee76500:   c4 e3 5d 0c c0 55 c5 e4 5c c8 c5 e4 58 c0 c5 fc
0x000000006ee76510:   29 01 c5 fc 29 49 20 c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00
0x000000006ee76520:   c5 fc 28 51 40 c5 fc 28 59 60 c5 ec 5c fb c5 ec
0x000000006ee76530:   58 d3 c5 c4 57 3d 26 41 84 00 c5 ec c6 df be c5 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000003e1130 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000058fc0120 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000000003e1130 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000009 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000000022fdd60 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000021fe800
RBP=0x00000000003e0870 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000000003e2130 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000006ee77580 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000006ee76490 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000005902e880 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000003d16a0 is an unknown value
R12=0x00000000003d1ea0 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000184 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000006fab8f20 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000002200000,0x0000000002300000],  sp=0x00000000022fdd60,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [xuggle7482689414368935779.dll+0x736520]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.IContainer_open__SWIG_1(JLcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer;Ljava/lang/String;IJLcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainerFormat;ZZ)I+0
j  com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.open(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer$Type;Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainerFormat;ZZ)I+19
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.open()V+20
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket()Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IError;+8
j  testmp4.TestMP4.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000005631f800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5712, stack(0x0000000058560000,0x0000000058660000)]
  0x0000000057d41000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1836, stack(0x0000000058410000,0x0000000058510000)]
  0x0000000057d40800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8572, stack(0x0000000058200000,0x0000000058300000)]
  0x0000000056318000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8172, stack(0x0000000057c40000,0x0000000057d40000)]
  0x0000000056316800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9060, stack(0x0000000057a00000,0x0000000057b00000)]
  0x0000000056313800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7208, stack(0x0000000057830000,0x0000000057930000)]
  0x00000000562b7000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9876, stack(0x0000000057700000,0x0000000057800000)]
  0x00000000562b0000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10068, stack(0x0000000057560000,0x0000000057660000)]
=>0x00000000021fe800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=8360, stack(0x0000000002200000,0x0000000002300000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000562aa800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000057370000,0x0000000057470000] [id=5480]
  0x0000000057de5800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000586c0000,0x00000000587c0000] [id=8516]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 28672K, used 8878K [0x00000000e0300000, 0x00000000e2300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 24576K, 36% used [0x00000000e0300000,0x00000000e0bab8e8,0x00000000e1b00000)
  from space 4096K, 0% used [0x00000000e1f00000,0x00000000e1f00000,0x00000000e2300000)
  to   space 4096K, 0% used [0x00000000e1b00000,0x00000000e1b00000,0x00000000e1f00000)
 ParOldGen       total 65536K, used 0K [0x00000000a0800000, 0x00000000a4800000, 0x00000000e0300000)
  object space 65536K, 0% used [0x00000000a0800000,0x00000000a0800000,0x00000000a4800000)
 Metaspace       used 5529K, capacity 5564K, committed 5888K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 645K, capacity 660K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011a10000,0x0000000011d10000] byte_map_base: 0x000000001150c000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000059fc4040
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012660000, 0x0000000013e40000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000013e40000, 0x0000000015620000)

Polling page: 0x0000000001c80000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1840Kb max_used=1840Kb free=243919Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002650000, 0x00000000028c0000, 0x0000000011650000]
 total_blobs=690 nmethods=352 adapters=251
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1.648 Thread 0x0000000057d41000  348       3       java.net.URLClassLoader$1::run (5 bytes)
Event: 1.649 Thread 0x0000000057d41000 nmethod 348 0x000000000281cd50 code [0x000000000281cec0, 0x000000000281d068]
Event: 1.649 Thread 0x0000000057d41000  349   !   3       java.net.URLClassLoader$1::run (63 bytes)
Event: 1.649 Thread 0x0000000057d41000 nmethod 349 0x000000000281c390 code [0x000000000281c560, 0x000000000281ca88]
Event: 1.649 Thread 0x0000000057d41000  350  s    3       sun.misc.Resource::cachedInputStream (20 bytes)
Event: 1.650 Thread 0x0000000057d41000 nmethod 350 0x000000000281bd90 code [0x000000000281bf00, 0x000000000281c2c8]
Event: 1.652 Thread 0x0000000057d41000  351  s!   3       java.net.URLStreamHandler::getHostAddress (54 bytes)
Event: 1.652 Thread 0x0000000057d41000 nmethod 351 0x000000000281b110 code [0x000000000281b2c0, 0x000000000281ba58]
Event: 1.659 Thread 0x0000000057d41000  352       3       java.lang.ref.WeakReference::<init> (7 bytes)
Event: 1.659 Thread 0x0000000057d41000 nmethod 352 0x000000000281ac10 code [0x000000000281ad80, 0x000000000281b030]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.081 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000e0497968) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.081 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000e0498c08) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.081 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000e0498dc0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.081 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000e0499fe8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.081 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000e049a1a0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000e0578158) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000e0578310) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.108 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000e057c238) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.108 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000e057c3f0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.135 Thread 0x00000000021fe800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000e07157c0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 1.654 loading class java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit$6
Event: 1.655 loading class java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit$6 done
Event: 1.655 loading class java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit$7
Event: 1.655 loading class java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit$7 done
Event: 1.658 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer$Type
Event: 1.658 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer$Type done
Event: 1.659 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer$Type$SwigNext
Event: 1.659 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer$Type$SwigNext done
Event: 1.659 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainerFormat
Event: 1.659 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainerFormat done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013fca0000 - 0x000000013fcd7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe
0x0000000077190000 - 0x0000000077339000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076f70000 - 0x000000007708f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefc210000 - 0x000007fefc27c000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefce80000 - 0x000007fefcf5b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefc650000 - 0x000007fefc6ef000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefcf60000 - 0x000007fefcf7f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefd110000 - 0x000007fefd23d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077090000 - 0x000000007718a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefce10000 - 0x000007fefce77000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefca10000 - 0x000007fefca1e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefd240000 - 0x000007fefd309000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefaa50000 - 0x000007fefac44000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefc280000 - 0x000007fefc2f1000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefcd40000 - 0x000007fefcd6e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefca20000 - 0x000007fefcb29000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000007fef3430000 - 0x000007fef34bd000     C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\AVG2015\avghooka.dll
0x000000005ade0000 - 0x000000005aeb2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000597c0000 - 0x000000005a043000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef5130000 - 0x000007fef5139000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefc7e0000 - 0x000007fefc82d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefc6f0000 - 0x000007fefc6f8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fef9010000 - 0x000007fef904b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefaf40000 - 0x000007fefaf4c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000077350000 - 0x0000000077357000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000000005c230000 - 0x000000005c23f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000005c200000 - 0x000000005c229000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000000005c1e0000 - 0x000000005c1f6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefd310000 - 0x000007fefe099000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefcb30000 - 0x000007fefcd33000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefbed0000 - 0x000007fefbedf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefb6c0000 - 0x000007fefb6d8000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefb3c0000 - 0x000007fefb407000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefc090000 - 0x000007fefc0ae000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefbd20000 - 0x000007fefbd2f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000000005c1c0000 - 0x000000005c1da000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefb660000 - 0x000007fefb6b5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefb650000 - 0x000007fefb657000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fef8730000 - 0x000007fef8757000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fef8780000 - 0x000007fef878b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef83c0000 - 0x000007fef83d8000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000007fef8050000 - 0x000007fef8061000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000000005ba80000 - 0x000000005ba91000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x000000006e740000 - 0x000000006fda5000     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\xuggle\xuggle7482689414368935779.dll
0x000007feefda0000 - 0x000007feefdb7000     C:\Windows\system32\AVICAP32.dll
0x000007feef200000 - 0x000007feef229000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVFW32.dll
0x000007fef63b0000 - 0x000007fef64d5000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: testmp4.TestMP4
java_class_path (initial): C:\Michal\Java Workspace\Xuggler\commons-cli-1.2-bin\commons-cli-1.2\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Michal\Java Workspace\Xuggler\xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar;C:\Michal\Java Workspace\Xuggler\logback-1.1.2\logback-1.1.2\logback-classic-1.1.2.jar;C:\Michal\Java Workspace\Xuggler\logback-1.1.2\logback-1.1.2\logback-core-1.1.2.jar;C:\Michal\Java Workspace\Xuggler\slf4j-1.7.10\slf4j-1.7.10\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;C:\Michal\Java Workspace\TestMP4\build\classes
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Michal\Xuggler\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Mingw\bin;C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
USERNAME=User
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.18409)

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 6253844k(2125080k free), swap 12505832k(7349476k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_40-b26), built on Mar  7 2015 13:51:59 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Mon Mar 23 20:32:59 2015
elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)
```

Or just a popup saying java stopped working with exit code:
Java Result: -1073741819

Comment: I know it's been 3 years but just wanted to let others know that this problem is still unsolved for xuggler ver 5.4.
We've checked in on few machines running java8 (64bit): Win7 x64, Win10 x64 and two Linux hosts.
Obviously, it happens only on Windows :D