# Failed to write core dump. minidumps are not enabled by default on client version of windows

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, xuggler, minidump

I have this Java class I am trying to run using Eclipse Mars.1 IDE.

Here's the code :

```
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader; 
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter; 
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory; 
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec; 

public class VideoToAudio {

public void convertVideoToAudio(){
    IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("C:/Users/hbxd78/Desktop/test.mp4");
    IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("C:/Users/hbxd78/Desktop/agf.mp3", reader);


    int sampleRate = 44100;
    int channels = 1;

    writer.setMaskLateStreamExceptions(true);
    writer.addAudioStream(1, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MP3, channels, sampleRate);

    reader.addListener(writer);

    while (reader.readPacket() == null) ;
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    VideoToAudio vta = new VideoToAudio();
    try{
        vta.convertVideoToAudio();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not open video file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

When trying to run the following code I get the following error shown in my Eclipse console :

### Here's the error log returned from program executions

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ee76520, pid=6852, tid=3424
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b18) (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b18 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle2013058311529011075.dll+0x736520]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000267e000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3424, stack(0x0000000002710000,0x0000000002810000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000006ed090, RBX=0x000000001aa90120, RCX=0x00000000006ed090, RDX=0x0000000000000009
RSP=0x000000000280e270, RBP=0x00000000006ec7d0, RSI=0x00000000006ee090, RDI=0x0000000000000004
R8 =0x000000006ee77580, R9 =0x000000006ee76490, R10=0x00000000006efe20, R11=0x00000000006f0430
R12=0x00000000006f0c30, R13=0x0000000000000004, R14=0x0000000000000184, R15=0x000000006fab8f20
RIP=0x000000006ee76520, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000280e270)
0x000000000280e270:   000000006ee76665 000000006ee774c5
0x000000000280e280:   000000006ee77505 000000006ee77545
0x000000000280e290:   000000006ee77585 000000006ee79426
0x000000000280e2a0:   000000006fab8f20 00000000006ed090
0x000000000280e2b0:   000000001aa925e0 0000000002bc74c0
0x000000000280e2c0:   3fe0000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000280e2d0:   40c7760000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000280e2e0:   3fe0000000000000 0000000000000001
0x000000000280e2f0:   000000001aa935e0 000000006ea45d24
0x000000000280e300:   3f40624dd2f1a9fc 0000000000000000
0x000000000280e310:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000280e320:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000280e330:   000000001aa9c4e0 000000006fab7320
0x000000000280e340:   0000000017568d9d 000000001aa90080
0x000000000280e350:   0000000000000001 00000000006ec7d0
0x000000000280e360:   00000000006ec850 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006ee76520)
0x000000006ee76500:   c4 e3 5d 0c c0 55 c5 e4 5c c8 c5 e4 58 c0 c5 fc
0x000000006ee76510:   29 01 c5 fc 29 49 20 c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00
0x000000006ee76520:   c5 fc 28 51 40 c5 fc 28 59 60 c5 ec 5c fb c5 ec
0x000000006ee76530:   58 d3 c5 c4 57 3d 26 41 84 00 c5 ec c6 df be c5 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000006ed090 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000001aa90120 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000000006ed090 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000009 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000280e270 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000267e000
RBP=0x00000000006ec7d0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000000006ee090 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000006ee77580 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000006ee76490 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000006efe20 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000006f0430 is an unknown value
R12=0x00000000006f0c30 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000184 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000006fab8f20 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000002710000,0x0000000002810000],  sp=0x000000000280e270,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [xuggle2013058311529011075.dll+0x736520]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.IContainer_open__SWIG_1(JLcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer;Ljava/lang/String;IJLcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainerFormat;ZZ)I+0
j  com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.open(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer$Type;Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainerFormat;ZZ)I+19
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.open()V+20
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket()Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IError;+8
j  VideoToAudio.convertVideoToAudio()V+50
j  VideoToAudio.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000018df2000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4048, stack(0x0000000019aa0000,0x0000000019ba0000)]
  0x0000000018d7c800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3660, stack(0x00000000197c0000,0x00000000198c0000)]
  0x0000000018d7b000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6928, stack(0x0000000019660000,0x0000000019760000)]
  0x0000000018d74000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2028, stack(0x0000000019250000,0x0000000019350000)]
  0x0000000018d72800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=684, stack(0x00000000194c0000,0x00000000195c0000)]
  0x0000000017b1e800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6244, stack(0x0000000019350000,0x0000000019450000)]
  0x0000000017ab7000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5412, stack(0x0000000018940000,0x0000000018a40000)]
  0x0000000017ab0000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5868, stack(0x0000000018c70000,0x0000000018d70000)]
=>0x000000000267e000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3424, stack(0x0000000002710000,0x0000000002810000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000017aaa800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000018a80000,0x0000000018b80000] [id=2800]
  0x0000000018e3e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000019970000,0x0000000019a70000] [id=1824]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 5326K [0x00000000d5b00000, 0x00000000d8580000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 16% used [0x00000000d5b00000,0x00000000d6033a28,0x00000000d7b80000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8080000,0x00000000d8080000,0x00000000d8580000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7b80000,0x00000000d7b80000,0x00000000d8080000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000081000000, 0x0000000086580000, 0x00000000d5b00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081000000,0x0000000081000000,0x0000000086580000)
 Metaspace       used 4376K, capacity 5216K, committed 5504K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 484K, capacity 528K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011f80000,0x0000000012380000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011b78000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005531a5b0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012da0000, 0x0000000014d60000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014d60000, 0x0000000016d20000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000240000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1548Kb max_used=1560Kb free=244211Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002bc0000, 0x0000000002e30000, 0x0000000011bc0000]
 total_blobs=534 nmethods=214 adapters=233
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 2.318 Thread 0x0000000018d7c800  210       3       java.lang.String::regionMatches (149 bytes)
Event: 2.318 Thread 0x0000000018d7c800 nmethod 210 0x0000000002d38a90 code [0x0000000002d38ce0, 0x0000000002d39978]
Event: 2.318 Thread 0x0000000018d7c800  211       3       java.lang.String::concat (47 bytes)
Event: 2.319 Thread 0x0000000018d7c800 nmethod 211 0x0000000002d41990 code [0x0000000002d41b60, 0x0000000002d42318]
Event: 2.320 Thread 0x0000000018d7b000  212       4       java.lang.String::indexOf (166 bytes)
Event: 2.321 Thread 0x0000000018d7c800  213       3       java.lang.ref.Finalizer::register (10 bytes)
Event: 2.321 Thread 0x0000000018d7c800 nmethod 213 0x0000000002d42690 code [0x0000000002d42820, 0x0000000002d42c48]
Event: 2.321 Thread 0x0000000018d7c800  214       3       java.lang.ref.Finalizer::<init> (23 bytes)
Event: 2.322 Thread 0x0000000018d7c800 nmethod 214 0x0000000002d42e10 code [0x0000000002d42fa0, 0x0000000002d43308]
Event: 2.327 Thread 0x0000000018d7b000 nmethod 212 0x0000000002d46590 code [0x0000000002d466e0, 0x0000000002d46bf8]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (1 events):
Event: 0.906 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002d2e190 method=java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read([BII)I @ 69

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5da38e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5da4878) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5da4a88) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5da59e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5da5bf0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.228 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5dda7a8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.228 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5dda9b8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.229 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5dde748) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.229 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5dde958) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.230 Thread 0x000000000267e000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError': org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder> (0x00000000d5de1d28) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u66\5298\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 199]

Events (10 events):
Event: 2.320 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/ICodec$Type
Event: 2.320 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/ICodec$Type done
Event: 2.320 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/ICodec$Type$SwigNext
Event: 2.320 loading class com/xuggle/xuggler/ICodec$Type$SwigNext done
Event: 2.321 loading class com/xuggle/mediatool/event/AddStreamEvent
Event: 2.321 loading class com/xuggle/mediatool/event/AddStreamEvent done
Event: 2.321 loading class com/xuggle/mediatool/event/AStreamCoderMixin
Event: 2.321 loading class com/xuggle/mediatool/event/AStreamCoderMixin done
Event: 2.321 loading class com/xuggle/mediatool/event/AStreamMixin
Event: 2.321 loading class com/xuggle/mediatool/event/AStreamMixin done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f020000 - 0x000000013f057000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\javaw.exe
0x0000000077a30000 - 0x0000000077bd9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077910000 - 0x0000000077a30000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefdc90000 - 0x000007fefdcfc000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x0000000075670000 - 0x00000000756f7000     C:\Windows\System32\SYSFER.DLL
0x000007feff830000 - 0x000007feff90b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007feff220000 - 0x000007feff2bf000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feffb90000 - 0x000007feffbaf000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe110000 - 0x000007fefe23d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077810000 - 0x000000007790a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefe2c0000 - 0x000007fefe327000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe440000 - 0x000007fefe44e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefdd40000 - 0x000007fefde0a000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefbf80000 - 0x000007fefc174000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefde10000 - 0x000007fefde81000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007feff1f0000 - 0x000007feff21e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefe330000 - 0x000007fefe439000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000056500000 - 0x00000000565d2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000054b10000 - 0x0000000055399000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fefd340000 - 0x000007fefd349000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007feff780000 - 0x000007feff7cd000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe450000 - 0x000007fefe458000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefb330000 - 0x000007fefb36b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefc7e0000 - 0x000007fefc7ec000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000077bf0000 - 0x0000000077bf7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000000006bdd0000 - 0x000000006bddf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000059300000 - 0x0000000059329000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java.dll
0x000000005d600000 - 0x000000005d616000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefe460000 - 0x000007feff1e9000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007feff440000 - 0x000007feff643000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefd930000 - 0x000007fefd93f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefce00000 - 0x000007fefce18000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefcae0000 - 0x000007fefcb27000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefc840000 - 0x000007fefc85e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd860000 - 0x000007fefd86f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x00000000592e0000 - 0x00000000592fa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefcda0000 - 0x000007fefcdf5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefd330000 - 0x000007fefd337000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefa3d0000 - 0x000007fefa3f7000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefa3c0000 - 0x000007fefa3cb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef9ba0000 - 0x000007fef9bb1000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000007fef9b10000 - 0x000007fef9b28000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x00000000592c0000 - 0x00000000592d1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\nio.dll
0x000000006e740000 - 0x000000006fda5000     C:\Users\hbxd78\AppData\Local\Temp\xuggle\xuggle2013058311529011075.dll
0x000007feea410000 - 0x000007feea427000     C:\Windows\system32\AVICAP32.dll
0x000007fedf3c0000 - 0x000007fedf3e9000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVFW32.dll
0x000007fef8300000 - 0x000007fef8425000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1255 
java_command: VideoToAudio
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\DecodeAndPlayAudio\bin;C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\DecodeAndPlayAudio\lib\JMF-2.1.1e\lib\customizer.jar;C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\DecodeAndPlayAudio\lib\JMF-2.1.1e\lib\jmf.jar;C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\DecodeAndPlayAudio\lib\JMF-2.1.1e\lib\mediaplayer.jar;C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\DecodeAndPlayAudio\lib\JMF-2.1.1e\lib\multiplayer.jar;C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\DecodeAndPlayAudio\lib\jmf-2.1.1e.jar;C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\DecodeAndPlayAudio\lib\jmf.jar;C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\DecodeAndPlayAudio\lib\JLayer1.0.1\jl1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\DecodeAndPlayAudio\xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar;C:\Users\hbxd78\workspaceNew\JARs\slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;.;.;C:\PROGRA~2\JMF21~1.1E\lib\sound.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\JMF21~1.1E\lib\jmf.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\JMF21~1.1E\lib;
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin;C:\msys\1.0\bin;\C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient\cteapis;C:\Users\hbxd78\Downloads\eclipse-java-mars-1-win32-x86_64\eclipse;
USERNAME=HBXD78
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.19045)

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8316404k(3383016k free), swap 12508872k(6751408k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b18) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_66-b18), built on Nov  9 2015 10:51:13 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Wed Jan 13 11:01:59 2016
elapsed time: 2 seconds (0d 0h 0m 2s)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried:

1. Updating Java to latest version.
2. Update Windows
3. Restart PC
4. Enable Mini-dumps through Advanced System Settings -- > Startup & Recovery -- > Settings -- > Choosing 'small memory dump'.
5. Update Graphic Driver to latest from official producer's (Nvidia) website.
6. deleting '.metadata' Folder from Eclipse's workspace folder and Imported the existing project.

So far no luck, my simple app is trying to extract audio from a video.

Comment: The 'failed to write core dump' message is not the cause of the failure. The class `com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.open` is calling JNI code (`com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.IContainer_open__SWIG_1`), this JNI code is causing an Access Exception. So it is probably a problem with how you are using the xuggler code or a bug in xuggler. Googling for `com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.IContainer_open__SWIG_1` shows several similar errors.

Comment: I have tried googling what you mentioned and haven't found anything useful. i have also edited my post and attached the source code I am  trying to run. what you suggest is that I might have Installed my xuggler not-properly but I'm kinda sure I did as i can run other apps using xuggler, there seem to be a problem with the

    while(read.readPacket() ==null)

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220114/xuggler-opening-mp4-files-crashes-blocks-program

Answer (score 15):

> Updating Java to latest version.

You have a problem in native code. Updating Java will unlikely help in that situation.

> Update Windows

This will only help if the native code that you use is updated through Windows Updates.

> Enable Mini-dumps through Advanced System Settings -- > Startup & Recovery -- > Settings -- > Choosing 'small memory dump'.

This setting is for kernel mode crashes (Blue Screen), not for application crashes (user mode). There is also a setting for application crashes (a Registry setting called LocalDumps) but it won't work for Java, since Java does its own exception handling.

To get crash dumps from Java 9 and above, use the following command line switch:

```
-XX:+CreateCoredumpOnCrash
```

On Java 8 and before, use the Windows specific command line

```
-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash
```

This will give you more details on what happens at the time of the crash. It will still be an `AccessViolation` but you'll get the callstack etc. - if you have the knowledge of debugging it with WinDbg or similar.

> Update Graphic Driver to latest from official producer's (Nvidia) website.

There's no evidence that this is related to the Graphics card.

Answer (score 6):

Had a similar issue with **JDK 1.8.0_261**, did downgrade the version to **JDK 1.8.0_251** and the same resolved the issue. May be you can try to upgrade the JDK version. Looks like a bug as per the below links:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15950

https://cassandra.link/feed/cassandra-windows-10-access-violation

Comment: You saved my life.