# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5 Cannot open

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I started learning Java a week ago when I bought my Java book. I had IntelliJ IDEA before because I was playing with Java.

Now, I bought my Java book (5 days ago) and my IntelliJ just didn't work. I get an error file on my desktop and I really don't know what to do.

What happens actually:

- I double click on intellij (no admin perms) it just opens in task manager for 10-20 seconds, then its gone.
- I right click on intellij and run it as admin, but the same thing happens.

Error: https://hastebin.com/qigamixete.tex

Comment: What video card and driver version do you use?

Comment: Here is my graphics card: [press](https://gyazo.com/7c7f2b6015d906b3793555f7b3da5151)

And also i updated my graphics card driver right now, it still wont work

Comment: Try running on Oracle Java: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879.

Comment: I have oracle java already

Comment: No, you are running on JetBrains Runtime: `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b12) (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12)`.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6653bf4f2af16f81311182d3255f3a81

Comment: IDEA comes with the bundled runtime, it doesn't usr your system JDK. Did you read the link from my comment above?

Comment: Yes. Give me a second.

Comment: I don't get it. What do I need to download? I can't even open the IDE, but on the site it talks about some sort of a plugin..

Comment: The document describes multiple ways of changing IDE JDK. One of them is setting environment variables, so you can set `IDEA_JDK` environment variable to the installation location of Oracle JDK and then run using `idea.exe`.

Comment: I don't have:
`C:\Users\%user%\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\config\jdks\`

Comment: You don't need it, please read the document carefully, its 100% accurate and describes several ways to change the runtime, use environment variables as already suggested above.

Comment: I'm reinstalling my Java dev kit and IntelliJ

Comment: I just realised; My IntelliJ worked before I updated my windows to 16299.19

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it, in a bit of time but it works now. I was using OpenJDK instead of OracleJDK

Answer (score 0):

This seems still an open and non-reproducable issue. I suggest you to update your JDK and graphics card. This might help you.

[Failed to write core dump. minidumps are not enabled by default on client version of windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762790/failed-to-write-core-dump-minidumps-are-not-enabled-by-default-on-client-versio)

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8182156

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179382

Comment: IntelliJ brings its own jdk.